# Easily Share a folder with a Windows computer in Fedora 15 (Gnome 3)?

Tags: fedora, file-sharing

I was trying out Fedora 15 but couldn't figure out something: How do I share a folder?

When doing some Googling all I could find were forum posts on how to manually configure samba with `smb.conf` (a place I refuse to go, it's 2011, people), and `gnome-user-share` which only shares `~/Public` and doesn't show up on my Windows computer.

I do know that at least in Ubuntu 10.10 with Gnome 2 all I had to do was right click on a folder and click Sharing. I'm looking for similar ease of use in Fedora.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I checked, Nautilus supported Samba share management out of the box, but I've yet to try GNOME 3 so that might have changed.

At any rate, I find the `system-config-samba` tool to be the easiest way to manage Samba shares.  To install it, run the following command on a terminal (as `root`):

```
yum install system-config-samba
```

Then, locate *Samba Configuration* in whatever it is GNOME 3 calls an application menu or run `gksu system-config-samba` on a terminal or by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.  From there you can create file shares, manage Samba user accounts, and configure the server easily.